# Generate numbers between 0 and N in a random order guaranteeing uniqueness with efficient memory cost

Tags: distributions, random-generation

I'm trying to think of a method i could use to generate the random numbers between 0 and N in a random order and with uniqueness that would use the smallest footprint of memory at the beginning and only increase the more numbers are generated.

The existing solution i have is (python code):

```py
def _generate_random_sequence(N: int):
    """
    Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm to generate a random sequence of numbers
    from 0 to N in a random order and without repetition.
    """
    numbers = list(range(N))

    for i in range(N-1, -1, -1):
        j = random.randint(0, i)
        numbers[i], numbers[j] = numbers[j], numbers[i]
        yield numbers[i]
```

But here we are allocating a list of size N right at the start, regardless of how many samples are iterated on. Ideally, memory cost should be 0 at the beginning and increase the more we iterate, reaching N.

Is there any algorithm to tackle this issue?

Comment: You could do rejection sampling: start by sampling any number between $0$ and $N$. Then, once you have already sampled a set $A$ of numbers, sample one number more, $x$. If you have already sampled $x$, i.e., $x\in A$, discard $x$ and sample another one. Then at any point in time, you will only need to store $A$. But this will get prohibitively costly as your sample size approaches $N$. Alternatively, only sample from among those numbers you have not yet sampled... but then you need to store the not-yet-sampled numbers.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "memory" as well as your computational model.  For instance, in a computational model where you can store arbitrary integers exactly, simply generate a uniform value between $0$ and $N!-1$ and apply any mapping you like from the integers $\{0,1,\ldots, N!-1\}$ to the permutations of $\{0,1,\ldots,N-1\}.$